# How to place many divs horizontally automatically?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am writing an online store. Accordingly, I have a list of goods (cards). How can I arrange them horizontally on the page so that I don't have to manually adjust each of them? I need the following result:

[image]

Now I do it through:

```html
 <div class="card">
        <img id="coffeeImage1" src="static/images/coffees-background.jpg" alt="Coffee" style="width:100%">
        <h1 id="name1">Название</h1>
        <p id="price1" class="price">price</p>
        <p id="weight1">weight</p>
        <p id="country1">country</p>
        <p><button>Добавить в корзину</button></p>
    </div>
```

```css
.card {
    position: absolute;
    left: 150px;
    top: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    max-width: 300px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial;
}

.price {
    color: grey;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.card button {
    border: none;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 12px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.card button:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

There are so many of them that I have to write each of them. The project uses `HTML` + `CSS` + `JAVASCRIPT` (no frameworks or third-party libraries).

Comment: Forget about `position:absolute` and above all, forget about `float`. Flexbox is our lord and saviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to use flexbox here. Style the parent-container of the cards with display: flex

For further details I can recommend [this article on flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

Add (display:flex;flex-wrap: wrap;) to the parent element of the card you will get the expected result.

```css
.f_container{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.card {
    position: relative;
    left: 150px;
    top: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    max-width: 300px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial;
    margin:20px;
}

.price {
    color: grey;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.card button {
    border: none;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 12px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.card button:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<div class="f_container">
    <div class="card">
        <img id="coffeeImage1" src="static/images/coffees-background.jpg" alt="Coffee" style="width:100%">
        <h1 id="name1">Название</h1>
        <p id="price1" class="price">price</p>
        <p id="weight1">weight</p>
        <p id="country1">country</p>
        <p><button>Добавить в корзину</button></p>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <img id="coffeeImage1" src="static/images/coffees-background.jpg" alt="Coffee" style="width:100%">
        <h1 id="name1">Название</h1>
        <p id="price1" class="price">price</p>
        <p id="weight1">weight</p>
        <p id="country1">country</p>
        <p><button>Добавить в корзину</button></p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <img id="coffeeImage1" src="static/images/coffees-background.jpg" alt="Coffee" style="width:100%">
        <h1 id="name1">Название</h1>
        <p id="price1" class="price">price</p>
        <p id="weight1">weight</p>
        <p id="country1">country</p>
        <p><button>Добавить в корзину</button></p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <img id="coffeeImage1" src="static/images/coffees-background.jpg" alt="Coffee" style="width:100%">
        <h1 id="name1">Название</h1>
        <p id="price1" class="price">price</p>
        <p id="weight1">weight</p>
        <p id="country1">country</p>
        <p><button>Добавить в корзину</button></p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <img id="coffeeImage1" src="static/images/coffees-background.jpg" alt="Coffee" style="width:100%">
        <h1 id="name1">Название</h1>
        <p id="price1" class="price">price</p>
        <p id="weight1">weight</p>
        <p id="country1">country</p>
        <p><button>Добавить в корзину</button></p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <img id="coffeeImage1" src="static/images/coffees-background.jpg" alt="Coffee" style="width:100%">
        <h1 id="name1">Название</h1>
        <p id="price1" class="price">price</p>
        <p id="weight1">weight</p>
        <p id="country1">country</p>
        <p><button>Добавить в корзину</button></p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <img id="coffeeImage1" src="static/images/coffees-background.jpg" alt="Coffee" style="width:100%">
        <h1 id="name1">Название</h1>
        <p id="price1" class="price">price</p>
        <p id="weight1">weight</p>
        <p id="country1">country</p>
        <p><button>Добавить в корзину</button></p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <img id="coffeeImage1" src="static/images/coffees-background.jpg" alt="Coffee" style="width:100%">
        <h1 id="name1">Название</h1>
        <p id="price1" class="price">price</p>
        <p id="weight1">weight</p>
        <p id="country1">country</p>
        <p><button>Добавить в корзину</button></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: grid` to arrange items in a grid. Wrap your cards in a div with a class "container"

Using the follow code:

```
.container {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
grid-gap: 40px;
}
```

You will be able to arrange your cards within a div. You can view the jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gnpLt6zh/). I also removed the margins and position styles for your cards since they are not needed as they interfere with the grid styling. Read more about grid [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp)